# Combine value from sqldatareader

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

i want to combine(concatenate) all row that come from a select statement, how can i do that please? i tried one but it return on the first record but i want the all rows into one single string can someone help please

```
If IsNumberExist() Then
   Using conss As New SqlConnection(_start)
       Dim sql4 As String = "SELECT Film.Title + ' ,   ' + Film.ParentControl + ', ' + '     SALLE : ' + Program.Venue +  ' ,' +'    SEAT AVAILABLE :' +  Cast(Program.Seat as varchar) + ' , ' +  '   SEAT PRICE :  Rs ' + Cast(Film.Price as varchar) AS Expr1 FROM Program INNER JOIN Film ON Program.FilmID = Film.FilmID"
       Dim myCommand1 = New SqlCommand(sql4, conss)

       conss.Open()

       Dim reader As SqlDataReader = myCommand1.ExecuteReader

       If reader.HasRows Then
          While reader.Read
              msg = reader.GetString(0)
          End While

          Dim message As String = msg
          Response.Redirect("http://localhost:9333/Ozeki?login=admin&password=abc123&action=sendMessage&messagetype=SMS&recepient=++23057864516&messageData=" + message)
      End If
   End Using
End If
```

Comment: I'm guessing you want a StringBuilder instead of that msg variable, which you keep replacing.

Comment: i don't if it is the name , but what i want is that all the row value, combine into a single string and is assigned to the variable msg

Comment: Having a "Response.Redirect" in the same method as a "SqlConnection" just made my skin crawl.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the strings as follows. In the following sample, I collect the parts in a list and concatenate them with [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (using ", " as the separator for the parts, but you can change this as you like):

```
Using reader As SqlDataReader = myCommand1.ExecuteReader
    If reader.HasRows Then
        Dim parts As New List(Of String)()
        While reader.Read
            parts.Add(reader.GetString(0))
        End While
        Dim message As String = String.Join(", ", parts)
        Response.Redirect("http://localhost:9333/Ozeki?login=admin&password=abc123&action=sendMessage&messagetype=SMS&recepient=++23057864516&messageData=" + message)
    End If
End Using
```

Please note that I've added a `Using` statement for the SqlDataReader.

Comment: The original code won't call `Response.Redirect(...` if there is no data.  Yours will.

Comment: @LarsTech, it work thank but, it appear on a single line, how make it appear on new line for a another row please

Comment: @user3503267: you need to change the page that the message is sent to for that. I'd suggest to choose a separator that will not be contained in your data. On the receiving page, replace the separator by `<br/>`.

Comment: @Markus the message is being send to ozeki sms message center, i'm doing an sms application that why i need each row on a separate line

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `msg` each time.  Use

```
msg = msg + Environment.NewLine + reader.GetString(0)
```

instead.

Or use a `StringBuilder`:

```
Dim sb As new StringBuilder()
While reader.Read
    sb.AppendLine(reader.GetString(0))
End While 

Dim message As String = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: i'm having a problem here, i'm trying to send the string to ozeki sms center but it does not  allow new line

Comment: @user3503267 so use `Append` instead of `AppendLine` (or separate with commas, depending on what your needs are)